# Powershell Office 365 unassigned licenses

Tags: powershell, office365

I am making reporting powershell script for our Office 365 users. I am currently making report with User name, email, license and date when the license was set. We will be using it for paying the licenses. The report will be run once every month. But when I unassigned license for user lets say 15th I need him to be in the report so we know we need to pay for the 15 days. Is there any command which tell me when the license was removed? I know about assignedtimestamp for assigning licenses. Is there something like that for unassinged licenses?

Comment: I don't think so, I had this exact issue and I built an Access database to track them all instead of using the information directly from Office365

Comment: God damnit, I thought so :). But thank you for the idea with database. Will look into it.